# Is there any way in Swift to define a collection which holds elements with different data types?

Tags: swift

In my specific case, I want something like:

```
var collectionWithDifferentTypes: [ObservableObject] = []
var elementOfTypeAWhichConformsToObservableObject = TypeA()
var elementOfTypeBWhichConformsToObservableObject = TypeB()
collectionWithDifferentTypes.append(elementOfTypeAWhichConformsToObservableObject)
collectionWithDifferentTypes.append(elementOfTypeBWhichConformsToObservableObject)
```

But letting arrays conform to ObservableObject is not possible. As the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) state, arrays, sets, and dictionaries can only contain elements of the same type. Is there any way in swift to have a collection similar to the one I've described above?

Comment: What do you want to do later with `collectionWithDifferentTypes` if, say, you could have it?

Comment: `But letting arrays conform to ObservableObject is not possible.` Why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Abion47 Error Message: Protocol 'ObservableObject' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) specifies an associated type `ObjectWillChangePublisher` that has to be defined in classes that conform to the protocol. There's an annoying trait of Swift that any protocol that specifies an associated type can't be used as a generic parameter since the runtime needs to know how the associated type is defined in order to effectively use it.

In order to use such a protocol as a generic type, you have to do what the error message specifies and use it as a generic constraint. That means that wherever you are defining the array has to be made into a generic context using `ObservableObject` as a constraint.

(class field)

```swift
class SomeClass<T: ObservableObject> {
  var myArray: [T] = []
}
```

(function variable)

```swift
func doAThing<T: ObservableObject>() {
  var myArray: [T] = []
}
```

(See [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements) for a more in-depth explanation on what this error means.)

Of course, there's always the nuclear option of just defining the array as `[Any]`.

Answer (score -2):

Two ways I can think of. If you subclass TypeB with TypeA then you could use  `var collectionWithDifferentTypes: [TypeA] = []` or if they both conformed the same protocol. No need for the subclassing. Just use `var collectionWithDifferentTypes: [protocolName] = []`

Comment: Subclasssing is not an option for me. Both conform to ObservableObject, but if I try to make the array conform to that, it states: Protocol 'ObservableObject' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements